# Weird follow path with icosphere

Tags: animation

I was doing a follow path work and something weird happened.It works perfectly fine with a sphere but if I use an ico sphere instead of the sphere it a dotted line appears(you know the one which indicates constraints) from the end of the curve to the ico sphere and it goes some weird movement.Does anyone have any idea why is it happening?

Comment: Its hard to tell without looking at the blend.

Comment: Hey thanks man,but I think I figured out the problem.See what I was doing was adding the curve and rotating it in the side orthographic view and I forgot the end and start of the curve so I added the sphere by selecting the end of the curve with 3d cursor.So,it acted weird,now it seems to be working fine.